# Применить атрибут при загрузке DOM

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется `<div>` с множеством разных ссылок `<a>`

Как методами JS применить ко всем ссылкам в контейнере атрибут `target="_blank"`

Идентификатор контейнера `id="footer"`

Answer (score 3):

Немного не успел, но всё же ;)

```js
[...footer.getElementsByTagName('a')].forEach(e=>{
  e.setAttribute('_target', 'blank');
  console.log(e);
});
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

P.S. `footer.getElementsByTagName('a')` - вернёт [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). [На англоязычном SO написано как работать с таким типом.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24266344/7791165)

Answer (score 2):

Если jquery:

```js
$('#footer a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Без jquery:

```js
const children = document.querySelectorAll('#footer a')

for(let e of children){
 e.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
 console.log(e) // чтобы показать результат
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
 <a href="/1">1</a>
 <a href="/2">2</a>
 <a href="/3">3</a>
</div>
```